# to print only ten words separated by tab in a line from a file in perl

Tags: perl

```
#! /bin/usr/perl
print "Enter your database name: \n";
chomp($db=<STDIN>);
open(R1,"$db")||die("error");
while ($line1=(<R1>)) {
    $l1=$line1;
    @arr1= split("  ",$l1);
    for $i=(0..9)
    {
        print  "@arr1[$i] \t";
        print join (@arr1), "\n";
    }
}
close(R1);
exit;
```

I want to have only ten words or (number also counted as a word) but what I am getting is only first the ten words are printed rest of the file is blank.

Desired output:

> 1 my name is a b c d e fg
>
> your name is micheal and you study in class 5

Comment: thank you for editing the piece .. can you please help me with an answer

Comment: What is your task? To get first 10 words from every line of the file?

Comment: First of all, `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: no,not the first ten but to print only ten words in each line from the file ..

Comment: But... How do you know which ten words from each line to print if it is not the first ten?

Comment: i have print the full file . the output file  must have ten words in each line...

Comment: i am  not extracting any words from the input the but printing ten word in a line from the input file till end .

Comment: can anyone please help with this code

Answer (score 1):

The initial problem with your code is syntax errors. The second problem is that you have not told Perl to help you write better code. Almost all Perl code should have `use strict; use warnings;`, so your code should start

```
#! /bin/usr/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
```

The `use strict;` will mean you must declare all the variables used, but that is a good thing. The two lines will also point out the syntax errors.

The only Perl programs that should not have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` are those where their author knows exactly why are being omitted and can explain the reasons to other people.

Comment: @user3483833 I suggest you add the two lines I indicated, then try to understand and fix the error and warning messages that are generated. If I tell you exactly what to do then your learning will be slower than if you work through the problems yourself. If you still have problems after adding the two lines then please update your question with the changed code and details of where you want help.

Comment: thanks for the help i ll do it  my self wasted so much of my time

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -wnlaF'\t' -E 'say join "\t", @F[0 .. (9 <= $#F ? 9 : $#F)]' input.txt > output.txt
```