# To print a para from a input file having five words in each line in output file in perl

Tags: perl

```
#! /bin/usr/perl
use strict ;
use warning;
print "Enter your database name: \n";

chomp($db=<STDIN>);
open(R1,"$db")||die("error");
 while($line1=(<R1>))
{
$l1=$line1;
@arr1= split("  ",$l1);
         for $i=(0..9)
           {
              print  "@arr1[$i] \t";
              print join (@arr1), "\n";
           }
}
close(R1);
exit;
```

To print a para from a input file having five words in each line in output file in perl

input :

My name is k s and i 
study in class 7. i am 12
year old and i like to travel all over the world.i like thai food

desired outut:
My name is k s
and in class 7. i
am 12 year old and
i like to travel all
over the world. i like
thai food

can you please help with the print function

Comment: possible duplicate of [to print only ten words seprated by tab in a line from a file in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778836/to-print-only-ten-words-seprated-by-tab-in-a-line-from-a-file-in-perl)

Answer (score 2):

Possible with a regular expression:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) { chomp;
    print "$1\n" while /((?:\w+\W*){1,5})/g;
}

__DATA__
My name is k s and i study in class 7. i am 12 year old and i like to
travel all over the world.i like thai food
```

*Gives:*

```
My name is k s 
and i study in class 
7. i am 12 year 
old and i like to
travel all over the world.
i like thai food
```